# Rotated text in a rotated figure

Tags: floats, typography, rotating

I have some full-page figure rotated ccw added using a `sidewaysfigure` environment.

The figures were originally made in Inkscape and were designed for non-rotated viewing and contain some text labels which are also rotated ccw. Luckily all text labels are added at TeX level inside a `picture` environment (exported from Inkscape).

When these figures are placed in a `sidewaysfigure` environment the rotated labels are rendered up-side-down wrt to the page orientation (page numbers, headers etc.). This seems wrong to me.

Question #1 (about typographical rules):

If there are any horizontal text labels in ccw rotated figures, should they be rendered upwards (cw rotated wrt the figure) or downwards (ccw wrt the figure)?

Question #2 (about LaTeX):
Since I expect the answer to the previous question is that the labels should be rendered upwards, is there any way of automatically rotating selected text labels 180 degrees? This should only affect rotated labels inside `sidewaysfigure` environments.

Below is a sample figure:

```
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1559.05517578bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.45454544)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{figure.pdf}}%
    \put(0.59090907,0.27272726){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\rotatebox{90}{\makebox(0,0)[b]{\smash{some text}}}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

and a `sidewaysfigure` environment instantiating it:

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
  \centering
  \def\svgwidth{\textheight}
  \resizebox{\textheight}{!}{
    \endlinechar=255\relax%
    \input{figure.pdf_tex}
  }
  \caption{...}}
  \label{...}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

Comment: haven't tried it, but why not pack the picture in a minipage before rotating it?

Comment: You need to place a `%` after the `{` on the `\resizebox` line and after the `}` of the `\input` line. Otherwise you will get an unwanted space on these places.

Comment: I would expect the figure to be the focal point of a `sidewaysfigure`. As such, the figure orientation should line up with the `sidewaysfigure` caption, which is rotated 90 degrees counter clock-wise. This seems to be your case already. However, I would rotate image elements so that they line up with whatever the image dictates. You don't want the reader to switch orientation for the caption, for the image, and for some of the overlaid text.

Comment: @Martin, thanks. I keep forgetting these all the time.

Comment: @Werner, are you aware of any guidelines or some credible publications following this convention? If I use it as well, what should I do with the page headers and number, which are currently facing upward (are rotated cw wrt to the figure)?

Comment: @Andrzej: No, not that could find from a quick search online - I thought this would have been included readily as part of author instructions for many journals. Either way, my reference is from a practical point of view; if the orientation of view is incorrect in portrait, a single turn (of the head) should result in the correct view. That is, in its entirety, the figure is either *viewed* in portrait (upright) or landscape (rotated) "mode."

Comment: @Werner, thanks. I'll leave the figures the way they are, then. I may have to find some justification for this decision, though, just in case someone has questioned it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect the figure to be the focal point of a `sidewaysfigure`. As such, the figure orientation should line up with the `sidewaysfigure` caption, which is rotated 90 degrees counter clock-wise. This seems to be your case already. However, I would rotate image elements so that they line up with whatever the image dictates. You don't want the reader to switch orientation for the caption, for the image, and for some of the overlaid text.

My reference is from a practical point of view; if the orientation of view is incorrect in portrait, a single turn (of the head) should result in the correct view (without any additional turns for text or explanation). That is, in its entirety, the figure is either viewed in portrait (upright) or landscape (rotated) "mode."

Publishers and journals have varying requirements regarding images in its submitted and eventual published form. This may even differ within journals from the same publisher. As such, I don't think there is a concrete standard or reference other than prevailing logic.